# Como obter o md5 de um registro e verificar se o mesmo é unico?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tenho uma necessidade atipica onde diversos registros são importados por lote, estes registros não tem identificadores únicos, cada registro tem informações sobre uma dívida.

Estou imaginando criar um md5 de cada registro para que não haja duplicidade. Claro que iria remover os campos de data como `created_at` e `updated_at`.

Pensei em utilizar o `Digest::MD5.hexdigest` onde criaria uma coluna `md5` e antes de salvar verificaria se existe um registro idêntico.

Quero saber se alguém aqui já teve um desafio parecido e possíveis soluções para este desafio. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está persistindo estes dados em um banco de dados? Porque não deixar a tarefa de saber se é único para o banco? Você pode colocar uma chave única na coluna que você deseja obrigar que seja o índice. Até fazer com que ela seja a chave primária (PK) dela em vez de um ID inteiro. Aliás o Rails costuma dar um pouco mais de trabalho caso uma PK não seja definida.

Para o caso de usar o MD5, acho que é possível mas vejo muitas soluções usando UUID. O PostgreSQL (caso esteja usando ele) vem com soluções build-in para gerar tanto MD5 quanto UUID.